# Can't start mongodb in ArchLinux

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongodb using `sudo pacman  -S mongodb`  in my 32-bit arch .
At first I run this `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` to create `/data/db`   ,and then  run `$ mongod`  ,then I got the following message :

```
mongod --help for help and startup options
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 
Sat Oct  6 11:4
5:29 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by default. Please use --           journal if you want durability.
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1146 port=27017    dbpath=/data/db/ 32-bit host=ftp
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] 
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] **       see    http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] **       with --journal, the limit is lower
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten]  
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] db version v2.2.0, pdfile version 4.5
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] build info: Linux brynhild 3.5.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP   PREEMPT Sun Aug 26 09:14:51 CEST 2012 i686 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] options: {}
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to   create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance  already running?, terminating
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 dbexit: 
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files... 
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 [initandlisten] couldn't remove fs lock errno:9 Bad file descriptor
Sat Oct  6 11:45:29 dbexit: really exiting now
```

---

what does `exception in initAndListen: 10309 Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating` mean?

Comment: even earlier there is indication that this is the wrong executable - you are on 64-bit architecture but this is a 32-bit mongoDB which is NOT suitable for production.  Permission denied could just be that /data/db directory is owned by a different user than you are starting the mongod process as.

Comment: @Asya Kamsky ,sorry for my mistake that it is 32-bit not 64-bit arch .

Comment: my mongodb.log https://gist.github.com/3843639 .  I am newbie to mongodb & node.js

Comment: I strongly recommend against using 32-bit platform for mongodb.  As far as the error, you are starting mongod as some user, but you probably created the /data/db directory as another user.  the permissions are such that mongod cannot create the files it needs.  fix permissions.

Comment: What's the difference between command `$ sudo rc.d start mongodb` and `$ sudo mongod`  to start mongodb service ? For me ,`sudo rc.d start mongodb ` works  but `$ sudo mongod` or `$ mongod` can't .

Answer (score 4):

You ran `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` as not yourself.  Now that directory is owned by root.

You need to chown the directory back to yourself before starting `mongod` otherwise mongod cannot access the directory write the files into it that are needed.

Please also find a 64-bit platform to run mongo - it's not really a very good idea to run it on 32-bit system unless this is just for playing around with.

Comment: What's the recommended way to install mongodb ? Is it using `npm install mongodb` or package magager like pacman or download the source code to `./configure & make & make install`?

Comment: After reinstall mongodb using pacman ,it works !